# Поиск макс. и мин. элементов двумерного массива

Tags: c, массивы, вывод

Есть двумерный массив 5х5, необходимо найти максимальный и минимальный элементы массива, после чего перенести минимальный в начало массива, а максимальный в конец. Собственно, ниже моя попытка реализовать это, проблема в некорректном выводе самого массива:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
int K[5][5];
int i, j, max=40, min=-20;
int iMax=0, jMax=0, iMin=0, jMin=0;
int tmp;
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<5; j++)    {
        K[i][j] = min+ rand()%(max + 1 - min);
     }
}
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
      if(K[i][j]<K[iMin][jMin]) {
          iMin = i;
          jMin = j;
       }
      if(K[i][j]>K[iMax][jMax]) {
          iMax = i;
          jMax = j;
       }
      }
   }
   tmp = K[0][0];
   K[0][0] = K[iMin][jMin];
   K[iMin][jMin] = tmp;
   tmp = K[4][4];
   K[4][4] = K[iMax][jMax];
   K[iMax][jMax] = tmp;
   for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<5; j++){
    printf ("%d\n", &K[i][j]);
}}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Ну и в чем именно проблема? Ваш вопрос так и напрашивается на закрытие по стандартной причине: *Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.*

Comment: спасибо за совет, отредактировал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что вам совсем не нужно писать `&` при выводе -

```
 printf ("%d\n", K[i][j]);
```

И - я бы выводил матрицы аккуратнее, и дважды - до и после преобразования:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int K[5][5];
    int i, j, max = 40, min = -20;
    int iMax = 0, jMax = 0, iMin = 0, jMin = 0;
    int tmp;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            K[i][j] = min + rand() % (max + 1 - min);
            printf("%4d ", K[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (K[i][j] < K[iMin][jMin])
            {
                iMin = i;
                jMin = j;
            }
            if (K[i][j] > K[iMax][jMax])
            {
                iMax = i;
                jMax = j;
            }
        }
    }

    tmp = K[0][0];
    K[0][0] = K[iMin][jMin];
    K[iMin][jMin] = tmp;
    tmp = K[4][4];
    K[4][4] = K[iMax][jMax];
    K[iMax][jMax] = tmp;
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("%4d ", K[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/wV1Gs0