# Дан одномерный вещественный массив X из n элементов

Tags: c

Дан одномерный вещественный массив X из n элементов.
Для каждой тройки идущих элементов массива((X0,X1,X2),(X1,X2,X3), ...,(Xn-3,Xn-2,Xn-1)) найти минимальный элемент.
Какая ошибка в коде и как вывести тройки элементов?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
  char *locale=setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  float *a;
  int n, i , in;
  float d,min;
  puts("Введите число элементов массива a");
  scanf("%d",&n);
    a = new float[n];
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    { printf("Введите число a[%2d]=",i);
      scanf("%f",&a[i]);       
    }
 d=0;
  for(i=0;i<*(a+1);i++)
  {
     printf("Первая тройка a[%2d]=%.2f\n",i,a[i]);
         min=a[i];
         if(min>a[i])
          {
            min=a[i];
          }
  }
      printf("min=%.2f \n", min);

  puts("Массив a");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("a[%2d]=%.2f \n", i, a[i]);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: И в чем проблема? Вы нажимали на кнопку "Задать вопрос", а вопроса по факту нет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/937365/281034

Comment: Задача максимально проста. Пишите функцию, которая вернет минимальное число из 3 (если не знаете как, то в гугле за 5 секунд ищется ), а далее просто цикл от `0` до `n - 2` и выводите минимальный элемент между `X[i], X[i + 1] и X[i + 2]`

Comment: Второй цикл: `for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)`

Comment: Пожалуйста если вам помог мой ответ, то отметьте его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа. Или скажите, что я упустил или где я что-то не понял и я подредактирую ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в коде? У вас в целом алгоритм не пойми, что делает :)

Например вот:

```
for(i=0;i<*(a+1);i++)
```

Цикл проходит от 0 до значения 2 элемента, если `a[1] = 100000` то цикл будет проходит от `[0, 100000)`.

Я так думаю вы пытались этим циклом найти первую минимальное значение в первой тройке, ну значит как минимум нужно было писать `i = 0; i < 3; i++`, но вам нужно пройтись по всем тройкам.

Значит берете и выделяете этот участок кода в отдельную функцию, которая будет принимать начало промежутка и будет возвращает минимальный элемент в тройке.

Например вот так:

```
float getMinTriple(float* a, int index) {
    //Сразу возьмем первый элемент как минимальный
    float min = a[index];
    //т.к. 1 элемент мы считай рассмотрели, то начнем с index + 1
    //и до index + 3 т.к. тройка
    for (int i = index + 1; i < index + 3; i++)
        if (min > a[i])
            min = a[i];
    return min;
}
```

Но можно было сделать проще, вот пример для понимания:

```
double min_triple(double x, double y, double z) {
    //Если x самый маленький возвращаем его
    if (x <= y && x <= z) return x;
    //Если y то возвращаем y
    if (y <= x && y <= z) return y;
    //иначе z
    return z;
}
```

Всё! Вся работа считай уже сделана, осталось только вывести минимальные элементы каждой тройки.

Например вот так:

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
    printf("min[%2d]=%.2f\n", i, getMinTriple(a, i));
```

А для 2 примера `min_triple` вот так:

```
for(i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
    printf("min[%2d]=%.2f\n", i, min_triple(a[i], a[i + 1], a[i + 2]));
```

Проходим от `0` до `n - 2` т.к. последняя тройка начинается с `n - 3` индекса. Иначе мы выйдем за пределы массива.

```
Индексы:  0 1 2 3 4
Значения: 2 3 4 1 5
```

Проверяем сначала `2 3 4` (от 0 до 2) тут минимальная `2`, потом `3 4 1` (от 1 до 3) тут уже `1`, и потом `4 1 5` (от 2 до 4) тут тоже `1`, а далее троек нет.

Результат получаем такой: `2 1 1`